# I need help for spawning enemies in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have problem spawning enemies in unity 2d. Enemies clones themselves too quickly and it lags. Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    public GameObject enemy;
    public float spawnTime = 5f;
    public float spawnDelay = 3f; 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating ("addEnemy", spawnDelay, spawnTime);
    }

    void addEnemy() {
        int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
        Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, 
spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I am currently making a 2D game where I have to spawn enemies and here is what code I used, edited for you of course:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject enemyPrefab;
    public float interval = 100;
    private float counter = 0;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        counter += 1;

        if(counter >= interval){
            counter = 0;
            Instantiate(enemyPrefab, transform.position,transform.rotation);

        }
    }
}
```

Simply create a new game object, put this script it, add the enemy prefab in the Game Object variable and you are set. You can edit the interval between each enemy with the interval variable. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: You should not do this in `FixedUpdate` but rather use a timer in `Update`

Comment: @derHugo would be useful to stipulate why - why should you use a timer in `Update` instead of using a counter in `FixedUpdate`?

Comment: I use FixedUpdate because the timing is Fixed? Haha

Comment: because you certainly don't want to rely on the value `100` ... `100` what? ^^ If you do it in `Update` you provide a value in **seconds** completely regardless how the physics is configured for the fixed physics updates interval. `FixedUpdate` should only be used for anything related to Physics

Comment: Well thats how i would do it. Its pretty much prefference. I like it that way thats why i showed it and as it seems my answer fixed OP's problem so whats bad about it? If they need to be more precise in seconds then they might as well do it in Update but i highly doubt they need it in seconds perfectly timed.

Comment: @derHugo well there's where I'll disagree - 100 in this case means 100 fixed update steps - spawning enemies using a timer breaks the game if the framerate tanks (unless you mean delta time). The game will spawn enemies more frequently than it should. Fixedupdate is guaranteed to be called to advance the physics timestep (which is a fixed period per physics frame and is configurable). I'd pick FixedUpdate since it's in lockstep with the actual physics which is guaranteed to spawn enemies at the correct time even if your game is struggling on a weak machine.

Comment: And btw actually I did ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/62894752/7111561

Comment: @Charleh ofcourse I mean using delta time which basically does exactly the same but you would configure directly the desired real-time seconds instead of having to calculate `x = real-time-seconds / physicsUpdateInterval` ...

Comment: I don't say yours is wrong .. at first I actually wanted to give you the hint that you should rather do it in `Update` since the UX is way better/more appealing doing it .. but as you continued to resist I decided to add an answer in order to guide future readers to fall into the same pitfall ... calling people jerks who try to improve a thread or post different solutions is not really professional

Comment: @derHugo i said that i used FixedUpdate because it used a fixed timestep, so i wouldnt have to use fixedDeltaTime or deltaTime. I didn't start the argument, i didnt post my answer to get into an argument.  The fact that i answered your questio and you continued by saying "you don't want to rely on the value 100...100 what?" Thats what i ont like in most "professional" programmers is that they always find something wrong in your code or try and make it more "professional" Listen, i does what its supposed to do. Spawn enemes in set interval.

Comment: @derHugo it gors from 0 to set interval. I dont need to know what it is i seconds and i ont new to know, and i dont want it in seconds. Its a simple example of a spawner for enemies, or if you are making a gun, shooting bullets and/or making a reloading timer or some timer that pauses for set interval. I dont need it in seconds. If i did i would have posted the answer for timer which uses seconds. Also  i didn't see the person asking the question needing it in seconds. They just wanted to make a spawner that works, they can set i terval for the spawning of enemies. Noting complicated. :D

Comment: `I dont need to know what it is i seconds and i ont new to know, and i dont want it in seconds` well when I design and implement a game I would prefer to set my intervals in seconds and not some magic number that eventually "works" .. that's what I mean ;)

Comment: @derHugo i'd say a magic number is without using a variable. Like if i only used 100 instead of the variable interval.

Comment: @xXrandomryzeXx a magic number is a value where you don't exactly know why you have to set exactly this value in order to make it work. `100` sounds just random .. why not `5` or `250`? You would as said everytime have to recalculate the value a) to find the desired interval in real-time and b) You also have to update every instance if you change the physics update interval to something different then the default 0.02 seconds

Comment: @derHugo well i usually avoid using some number which is not a variable of sort because thats for me a magical number. I guess not kniwing ti what yiy have to set it is a magical number too

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming they are spawning more than every 3 seconds? Do you have multiple 'EnemySpawner' scripts attached to objects in the scene?

edit sounds like you have an ‘EnemySpawner’ script in your prefab, remove it from prefab and put it on a separate GameObject in your scene.

Comment: No, I only have it on my player gameObject. If I put it on my enemy gameObject, enemies just won't spawn.

Comment: It is weird that the game object clones has (Clone)(Clone) written on it.

Comment: i updated my answer let me know if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You should not as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61723858/7111561) use `FixedUpdate` for this! It uses `100` fixed update steps .. but who wants to calculate how long this actually takes?

By default fixed update step is `0.02s` so `100` means `2` real-time seconds - but what if you change the fixed update step for any reason?

I would rather do it using a simple timer in `Update`:

```
public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject enemyPrefab;
    // In seconds
    [SerializeField]private float interval = 2f;
    private float timer = 0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if(timer >= interval){
            timer = 0f;
            Instantiate(enemyPrefab, transform.position,transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Actually what you had should also work! Depends of course also on the values you set via the Inspector.

**BUT** What I can see from the image you posted is: In `enemy` you referenced the object itself!

- => The next time there are 2 enemy instances including this spawner
- => The next time there are 4 enemy instances including this spawner
- => The next time there are 8 enemy instances ...
- => etc

Therefore they are called `Enemy[Clone]` then `Enemy[Clone][Clone]` then `Enemy[Clone][Clone][Clone]` etc so

Not sure if this was intended but I would rather put the spawner script on **one single** object in the scene and rather reference a prefab **without** an additional spawner script.